# Persist changes to core data item from SwiftUI view

Tags: swift, core-data, data-binding, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app that is to display a number of entries from a Core Data database. Basically just about what the XCode template for such apps implements.

I've made two changes:

1. I put the code for the list item view into a separate file (`BookmarkableItemView`)
2. I added a property `bookmarked` to the item, which I called `BookmarkableItem`

The code in my view to show the list of items is now:

```
List(bookmarkableItems) { item in
    BookmarkableItemView(item: item)
}
```

In `BookmarkableItemView`, the item property is an `@ObservedObject`.

Now, my `BookmarkableItemView` also contains a button that should toggle the `bookmarked` property on the item that the view represents. All fine and well - this is easy. But now I have to persist the changes...

I can think of the following two solutions:

- Pass an action (simple a `(BookmarkableItem) -> Void`) to the `BookmarkableItemView` that's then called when button in the view is pressed
- Have the view itself save the managed object context

The latter is  a no-go in my opinion. The first solution works. There's now an `bookmarkAction` property in the `BookmarkableItemView`, so the above code looks like that:

```
List(bookmarkableItems) { item in
    BookmarkableItemView(bookmarkAction: { toggleBookmark(item) }, item: item)
}
```

The action is called by the `BookmarkableItemView` and as a consequence, the `toggleBookmark(_ item:)` method is called.

But somehow I feel that I'm missing something about bindings in SwiftUI that would make the process easier? How can I have my parent view get a notification when a sub view performs changes to the data model so I can persist them?

Comment: `onDisappear` check if `item.hasChanges`. I’m not sure if it works but you might be able to use `onChange` on `item.hasChanges`

Comment: `onChange` on `BookmarkableItemView` for `item.bookmarked` actually works!! Can you write this as an answer so I can upvote and accept?

Comment: I added it. I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onDisappear` check if `item.hasChanges`

or use `onChange` on `item.hasChanges`

Comment: I actually implemented onChange and it works fine.